# How should I deal with posts that have been edited to replace the content with off-topic content?

Tags: support, edits, faq-proposed

I recently saw a question that was off-topic. Once I went to the revision history, I could see that the OP had changed the content of the question completely, thus making it off-topic.

In cases like this, what should be done? Should I flag it as "Blatantly off-topic", or should I roll the post back?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should roll the post back. If you can fix the question, you should, because the question still has a possibility of adding value to the Stack Overflow community.

If the user rolls back ***your*** edit, resulting in a rollback war, then flag for a mod and move on. We're all <sub>in theory</sub> adults here, so let's act like adults.

Comment: And... your edit resulted in a "rejected edit". Seems someone else perhaps didn't notice your pending rollback or for some reason chose to not approve it. I'm not sure how that makes for an incentive.

Comment: @Scratte That's not the case. The rejection reason reads "This item is no longer reviewable." No one actually reviewed it. I think that someone with enough rep edited it.

Comment: @Scratte: That's my fault. I didn't read GalaxyCat105's (original) answer properly and just read "I rolled it back" (I missed the "edit" part). I then went to the question and saw that it wasn't rolled back, so I simply did that. GalaxyCat105, sorry for the rejected edit!

Comment: I mean it's a good answer that I've seen come up dozens of times over the years, but this is not specific to Stack Overflow is it?

Comment: @Scratte There are good arguments for a 2k+ user just rolling back a post, rather than approving an edit from a user with <2k which *claims* to be rolling back the post. Users with >2k rep have an actual "rollback" button, which is available on the revisions page. It records it in the edit history as an actual rollback. In order to review an edit which claims to be rolling back the question, the reviewer would need to carefully verify in the diff-view and other available views that the *only* change was that the post was *actually* rolled back. Doing so for a long post is a *lot* of work.

Comment: @Scratte I'd much rather see an actual "rollback" in the edit history, because people reading it know *exactly* what *really* happened, rather than an edit which shows as a normal edit, but states that it's a rollback. Without a detailed check of the edit (by reviewers, and potentially people who visit the revision page after the edit is applied), you never know that's *actually* what was done. Yes, this means that my opinion is that rollbacks should be done by users with >2k rep, even if that means invalidating an edit by a <2k user which purports to be rolling back the post.

Comment: @Makyen That makes perfect sense. I think this Answer should reflect that, so <2K users don't start trying to manually edit posts to a previous identical version, but wait until they are >2K users using the rollback option :)