# How can I prevent an edit war happening when someone edits a post of mine?

Tags: support, edits, faq-proposed, edit-wars

> Disclaimer: this is a proposal for a separate FAQ item dedicated to handling edit wars and not a question per se

Someone edited a post of mine, but I disagree with the edit - how should I proceed? Also, I am unsure if rolling back the edit to the previous revision is the best course of action as it may lead to us overriding each other in an endless loop of edits or rollbacks - are there any processes in place to prevent this from happening?

The "[how to handle edit wars?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387182/how-to-handle-edit-wars)" Q&A and the corresponding duplicate target "[how do I raise a flag without getting declined by moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322511/edit-war-how-do-i-raise-a-flag-without-getting-declined-by-moderator)" deal with the edit wars already happening on someone else's posts or from an editor's point of view, as well as focus on flagging for moderator attention.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401269/how-should-i-deal-with-posts-that-have-been-edited-to-replace-the-content-with-o

Comment: @10Rep - agreed, a useful one - in light of complaints about good editors popping up from time to time and [today's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407362/11407695), I thought that the FAQ will benefit from a separate entry dealing with edits that do not deface the post but one simply disagrees with. Probably the one your referenced should be included in the question as a reference point - will try to think about a good way to incorporate it

Comment: So you know that [How to handle edit wars?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387182) exist and yet neither question nor answer indicate why a separate Q/A for the post owner is warranted, although both, owner and editor, should act the same.

Comment: @Tom - note that this Q&A, however prominent, deals with flagging for moderator attention when someone chances (or participates) in a rollback war. It is neither general guidance nor it is a FAQ item (both points addressed in the question - but I, of course, am not adamant about the wording if find it insufficient and will gladly accept any reasonable amendment). I also have no issue in generalizing it for both parties, but I firmly believe we should have a standalone FAQ item on such an issue.

Answer (score 5):

The guiding principle for resolving edit (rollback) wars (see [glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/786798)) should be trying to exit as early as possible. These wars usually have several levels of escalation:

1. The first edit - if you at least *partially* agree with the edit, it is best to accept it and optionally modify what you disagree with (always check if the edit complies with the editing etiquette first - see [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/786798)).
2. The first rollback - if you completely disagree with the edit, roll it back. If possible, provide a justification for the rollback under the post in a temporary comment (don't forget to clean up!), but avoid getting in a drawn-out conversation about it should the editor reply: comments [are not for extended discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
3. The first counter-rollback - if there is clear evidence of a war starting *and* you think the edit is actually **harmful**, [flag for moderator attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322512/11407695). But be sure this is obvious for an external observer, or the flag is likely to be declined.
4. The rollback loop - if you do end up in such a loop, just be aware that after **2 rollbacks in short succession by the same user** (see [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222644/786798)) an automatic flag is raised for a moderator to handle. At this point, just stop and put your trust in moderators being able to handle the situation.

To sum up, the sooner you reach the end, the better - strive to avoid the automatic moderator flag from being raised. Finally, the normal flow of editing leading to a rollback war and its resolution looks like below:

[image]

Comment: The flowchart seems to be missing a few labels on the arrows, e.g. probably a “No” at the top arrow from “2nd rollback in short succession?”, and the arrows going away from “The editor rolls back the edit” are both unlabeled, so it’s a bit confusing to follow this flowchart.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - that's a bit of a difficult one, the problem is the decision: the 2nd rollback happens regardless of whether or not the loop proceeds, but only when it is the second rollback in short succession the moderator flag is raised. I am really unsure how a UML diagram can convey "loop regardless" better - do you have an idea? It's the best that I could think of initially, maybe after I mull over it a bit more, I'll find a less confusing solution..

Comment: ^ btw, if somebody has an idea, I am really all ears, still unsure how to convey it